# Performance of StringBuilder on Mono

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I've the following code on a small project

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(itunesLibraryPath);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (string line in lines)
    builder.Append(line.Replace(currentPathPrefix, destPathPrefix));
File.WriteAllText(itunesLibraryPath, builder.ToString());
```

Works great on windows, then I ported it to IOS with Mono but it just takes forever on the `foreach`

Any ideas about the `StringBuilder.Append()` performance on Mono?

Thanks

Comment: The bottleneck might very well be `String.Replace()` instead of `StringBuilder.Append()`. Unless a profiler told you otherwise?

Comment: (Please don't use tabs when pasting code in Stack Overflow.)

Comment: I've just noticed that your code is going to end up putting all the text on a single line, as you're effectively removing line breaks. Is that deliberate?

Comment: You failed to provide enough info on the environment. Did you run this piece of code on normal Mono runtime on Mac? Or on MonoTouch in the simulator? Or on MonoTouch in the device?

Comment: How many lines are there in each case?

Comment: About 10000 lines, I run it on Mono runtime on Mac